# How do I add megabytes to free space when creating partitions to dual boot ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, dual-boot

So I was using this manual to dual boot ubuntu: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/dual-boot-ubuntu-15-04-14-10-and-windows-10-8-1-8-step-by-step-tutorial-with-screenshots

I got into a conundrum when the *free space* was only one megabyte.  My disk space however was ~739292MB.  How do I add more MB to free space?

If this has an obvious answer, please don't get mad, I'm just very nervous of doing something wrong.  Asking you geniuses to verify a guess would be better than guessing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the language used in the tutorial refers to unpartitioned space as "free space". They aren't quite the same thing. According to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot), you can select an existing partition (the one Windows is installed on), and adjust the size to increase unpartitioned/free space. Then install Ubuntu in that space.

Comment: If I select it, and press "-", it all goes to free space.  Would the unused megabytes automatically go back to where it started (/dev/sda4)?  Or would there be problems with booting w10 after installing ubuntu?

Comment: No. You're going to have two partitions, one for Windows and one for Ubuntu, and each partition is going to have a certain amount of unused space on it. When you hit the "-" that probably makes the Windows partition the smallest size it can be given the amount of data it currently contains, but if you set the partition to be that size it wouldn't have any space for new data and likely Windows wouldn't boot. Your best bet is to figure out the minimum partitioned space Ubuntu wants, and shrink the Windows partition by that much.

Comment: How do I shrink the Windows partition?

Comment: [Recommended reading](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition)